# Connect a GPU to a mobile FPGA using

Tags: electrical-engineering, embedded-systems, computer-engineering, computer-hardware

Please indicate if this question would be better asked on other fora, I'm not an engineer but computer scientist, and have very little experience with FPGA's / ASICs.

As far as I understand from what I have read online, FPGA's can take up the role of compiled C/C++ and even OpenCL programs and simulate output of a GPU.

My question is if it would be possible to connect a normal desktop PC GPU (NVidia) to an FPGA such as from Xilinx / Lattice Crosslink such that the video signal can be re-processed afterwards? Would this be possible with a DisplayPort or HDMI connection?

Alternatively, if the processinig is entirely moved to the FPGA, is it common to have high bandwith connections (order of > 10Gbps) into an FPGA?

Comment: Are you trying to re-process the video output signal from the HDMI output out of a PC?

Comment: Yes that is indeed the idea

Comment: This can be done, may I ask what are you trying to do with the FPGA. Also do you plan to feed the output to another display

Comment: In the current setup, the FPGA is driving the display hardware, i.e. rows and columns. In a next step the FPGA may take over the role of a GPU if FPGA resources are sufficient (i.e. processing power and input bandwidth), and maybe some additional filtering / interlacing /.. No other display would be involved.

Comment: @MahendraGunawardena How can this be done?

Comment: I will try to respond to this sometime today.

Comment: I found a bunch of Xilinx boards that can take in lvds at rates that should support hdmi2. My question is now mainly if such fpga's are strong enough to match gpu compute power.

Comment: The is the research I was hoping do before responded to you. So what you need to figure the output rate of hdmi. There will be lag due to re-processing. Depending on you application it me be very minimal. The new FPGA can run very fast. You will have to share some details of what you trying to provide a good answer

Comment: Well I'm not in a position to provide a lot of details, and from the documentation I learned already quite a lot. Still the practicalities of connecting fpga's to GPU's might a bit more involved than simply putting a puzzle. In any case thanks for the feedback so far!

Comment: The FPGA is very good at doing tasks that are paralell in nature, but quite fixed in processing size. The fabric of the fpga is limited in size, it also has limitted memory, though you could add more on board. The GPU can do much more complex processing is more flexible and much easier to implement. A bit depending on the task at hand